# Select statement inside a loop in a Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, date, stored-procedures

Can we use Select statement inside a loop in a Mysql Stored Procedure?

why is the code  wrong

```
create procedure AbsentReportproc (INOUT fromdate DATETIME, INOUT todate DATETIME)
as
begin

DECLARE startdate DATE;
DECLARE enddate DATE;
DECLARE nofdays INT;
DECLARE counter INT;
DECLARE countdate DATE;
startdate=fromdate;
enddate=todate;
countdate=fromdate;

nofdays=DATEDIFF(DAY,startdate,endate);
counter=1;

while counter<=noofdays
loop

select   CARDNO from test_prefixmaster
where CARDNO not in (  select CARDNO from test_prefixtransactions where Date(S_DateTime)=countdate)

set countdate=countdate+1;
set counter=counter+1;
end loop;

end//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AbsentReportproc`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AbsentReportproc`(IN _fromdate DATETIME, IN _todate DATETIME)
BEGIN 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE daterange (dte DATE); 

    SET @counter := -1;
    WHILE (@counter < DATEDIFF(DATE(_todate), DATE(_fromdate))) DO 
        INSERT daterange VALUES (DATE_ADD(_fromdate, INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 DAY));
    END WHILE;

    SELECT tp.cardno, tp.EMPCODE, tp.DEPARTMENT, GROUP_CONCAT(d.dte) Absentddate, COUNT(tp.cardno) Totalnoofabsentdates
    FROM test_prefixmaster tp JOIN daterange d 
    LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt ON tp.cardno = tpt.CARDNO AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
    WHERE tpt.CARDNO IS NULL 
    GROUP BY tp.cardno;

    DROP TABLE daterange;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can we use Select statement inside a while loop?

Comment: Yes but it will return output with tables noofday time. Means noofdays has value 4 than youroutput contans 4 tables

Comment: What is the reason for use of while loop in your procedure. Explain what exactly you want to do with table structure, sample dat and output.

Comment: I have two tables 1)test_prefixmaster and 2)test_prefixtransactions ,I want to find the Employees who were absent between two given dates? Transaction table contains the records who were present on the particular datetime,If an Employee absent to the office then no record will be inserted into the Transaction table?

Comment: I want to find Empcode ,Dept,Name,Absentdate for two given dates?

Comment: @PavanKumarCheck my updated answer and check the query it give you perfect result or not and feel free to ask me if you find any issue.

Comment: Add the output for your example

Comment: My output should be  Empcode ,Dept,Name,Absentdate for two given dates?

Comment: Please add sample so I can get more idea about how can i update the query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21944/discussion-between-saharsh-shah-and-pavan-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need a loop for this. You can do so:

```
SELECT
  p.CARDNO, 
  COUNT(CARDNO) AS countdate
FROM test_prefixmaster p
INNER JOIN test_prefixtransactions   t ON p.CARDNO = t.CARDNO
WHERE Date(t.S_DateTime) BETWEEN fromdate 
                             AND todate
GROUP BY p.CARDNO;
```