# Mysql show everyday between even if there are no results

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following query

```
SELECT SUM(value1 +value2) AS total  ,created_at
FROM mytable
WHERE created_at 
BETWEEN '2013-10-1' AND '2013-10-19' 
GROUP BY created_at
```

which returns

```
## total | created_at ##
  2500   | 2013-10-01
  6546   |  2013-10-05
```

but I want

```
## total | created_at ##
   2500  |  2013-10-01
   0     |   2013-10-02
   0     |   2013-10-03
   0     |   2013-10-04
   6546  |   2013-10-05
```

I'd like to return 0 for dates with no sums so the table shows everyday between the range
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can create a stored procedure to do this. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099479/select-statement-inside-a-loop-in-a-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: Choices: 1. sproc, 2. UNION, 3. utility table, 4. application level code

Comment: how can I make a union?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like it's described here:

[Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

But that would mean to create an extra table. Anyway, i think it's better that you do it at code level... why don't you do it that way?

Comment: I thought there would be a function to do it at db level. it seems like writing this at the application level is the best approach thanks.